# Default value in object property if not exist

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop, model-view-controller

I want to learn OOP to get my controllers more clean. So on my website, I get some products with their `image_name` from database. When a `image_name` is not set I want to set a default one. I don't want to make any if else in my view or model to check if image is set so I made a new class with some property and models. Here I check what I need and so my controller is more clean.
In my view I use the `$product->image_name` where `image_name` is the name of column in database, but using my class I want `image_name` to be the `imagefromdb.jpg` or `defaultimage.jpg` if is not set. How can I call this class in my controller to work?

This is my class:

```
class Product
{

    private $_product;
    private $_resolution;

    public function __construct($product, $resolution){

        $this->_product = $product;
        $this->_resolution = $resolution;
    }

    public function products() {

        foreach($this->_product as $product){
            $product->nume_imagine = $this->parse_image_name($product);
        }

        return $this->_product;

    }


    public function product() {

        $this->_product->nume_imagine = $this->parse_image_name($this->_product);

        return $this->_product;

    }


    private function parse_image_name($product)
    {
        if($product->nume_imagine):
            $image = base_url('assets/uploads/'.$product->id_produs.'/'.$this->image_resolution($product->nume_imagine, $this->_resolution));
        else:
            $image = base_url('assets/images/no-product-image-available.png');
        endif;
    }

    private function image_resolution($image_name, $resolution) {

        $image = explode('.', $image_name);
        return $image[0].'_'.$resolution.'.'.$image[1];
    }
}
```

And controller:

```
$best_offer     = new Product($this->products->best_offer(), 270);
```

but I get empty on image_name property.

Comment: _"but not working."_  Really?

Comment: ternary operator perhaps?

Comment: Sorry, I edited. No value for image_name

Comment: In your construct, you could put `$this->image_name = 'defaultimage.jpg';` then overwrite later on.

Comment: Although if you do multiple using the same object you will probably end up using the last-used image since it was assigned something else, so probably as @Fred-ii- says, a ternary is the best method.

Comment: @Rasclatt I tend to think so. It'll be cleaner than doing an `if/elseif/else` IMHO.

Comment: Offtopic: Why are you passing `$this->_product` to a private function (`parse_image_name`)? The function can access the variable by its own and you cannot call that function anywhere else.

Comment: @moorscode I pass there the current product from foreach. In constructor I pass a object with multiple products and I parse each one.

Comment: Please mind that if you call the `product` or `products` functions twice it will run the code twice and append the name to itself.

Comment: There is no `image_name` property. `nume_imagine`?

Comment: @trincot I translated in my text so you can understand. @moorscode I call twice but different objects as param. `$cea_mai_buna_oferta  = new Product($this->produse->best_offer(), 270);
  $produse_noi   = new Product($this->produse->entries_by_limit(0, 10, null), 270); $data['cea_mai_buna_oferta']  = $cea_mai_buna_oferta->product();
  $data['produse_noi'] = $produse_noi->products(); `

Comment: I'd call cleanest way default value in DB field on insert. If nothing passed when inserting new product, default should be string of `default_image.jpg` location. Than you pull db records in same maner without thinking what is there. You'll get appropriate location string either specific image either default one.

Comment: I can't do this because the inage_name is not column from products, is the result of join with images column. And if a product does not have a image that mean in images is not inserted a row for that product and I don't have where to set a default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `parse_image_name` is not returning anything. If you return the `$image` variable it will be set like you expect it to.

```
private function parse_image_name($product)
{
    if($product->nume_imagine):
        $image = base_url('assets/uploads/'.$product->id_produs.'/'.$this->image_resolution($product->nume_imagine, $this->_resolution));
    else:
        $image = base_url('assets/images/no-product-image-available.png');
    endif;

    return $image;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This was the problem. Do you think the code is dry? 

Offtopic: sebastianvirlan.com me also photographer :)

Comment: I think you should put the logic for multiple Products outside of the single Product instance. Make a list of Product instances and apply logic to that. Other than that you are not repeating yourself, so in a way it is DRY.

Comment: Offtopic: nice work, always good to meet coding photographers ;)

Comment: I don't really understand. So then I make foreach even if I have 1 product? If you are kind please show me your logic on pastebin.com

Comment: This is how I get from database: $result = $this->db->get();
        return $result->result(); so I already get a object with a lot of products.

Comment: It's very hard to guess what goes on in your system, so I can't really tell you what I think would be the best approach to this functionality.